# postgres - cannot access ENUM datatype

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic

I created a table using sqlalchemy and alembic. I added a ENUM Datatype for gender and it is available in the database. But when I Try to do an POST request to the table, It gives the following error,

```
{
  "some error": {
    "code": "f405",
    "statement": "INSERT INTO users (uuid, user_name, first_name, last_name, middle_name, date_created, gender) VALUES (%(uuid)s, %(user_name)s, %(first_name)s, %(last_name)s, %(middle_name)s, %(date_created)s, %(gender)s) RETURNING users.id",
    "params": {
      "uuid": "d8ab277b-6ddf-4cf7-8845-66cdbff2ac54",
      "user_name": "chanleeip",
      "first_name": "xxx",
      "last_name": "yyy",
      "middle_name": null,
      "date_created": "2024-01-08T19:36:02.272035",
      "gender": "male"
    },
    "orig": {},
    "ismulti": false,
    "hide_parameters": false,
    "detail": [],
    "connection_invalidated": false
  }
}
```

I checked the values present in the ENUM Datatype, it is the same value .  Don't know what is causing the error.

Following is the code, I used using alembic to create the table

`def upgrade() -> None:     gender_types=ENUM('male','female','non_binary',name='gender_types')     op.create_table(         'users',         Column('id',Integer,primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),         Column('uuid',UUID(as_uuid=True),default=uuid.uuid4,autoincrement=False,primary_key=True),         Column('username',String(30),nullable=False,unique=True),         Column('first_name',String(30),nullable=False),         Column('last_name',String(30),nullable=False),         Column('middle_name',String(30),nullable=True),         Column('timestamp_created',TIMESTAMP(timezone=False),default=func.now()),         Column('gender',Enum('male','female','non_binary',name='gender_types'),nullable=True) )`

I tried creating a new table and repeated the same procedure . It didn't work. But that time, the enum dataType was not created and some key_errors came , but i fixed that. But now, Can't do even GET requests.

Comment: It could be me, but I don't see any error message. At least not any message from the database.

Comment: Yes. It was an error from my end. I had variables names slightly differnce (missing _ btw words). Thank you for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Got it Fixed. Need to have the same variable names in sqlalchemy models and alembic models.